# Typesetting fillable PDF forms with `hyperref`

Tags: hyperref, forms

I'm trying to create a fillable PDF form with hyperref and I want there to be a long line instead of a box for a text field. At the moment I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand\LayoutTextField[2]{%
    #2
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        Name: \dotfill$\overset{\TextField[width=4cm,borderwidth=0pt]{\null}}{\rule{4cm}{.4pt}}$
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

This works and achieves what I want but I was just wondering if there was a better way to do it? For some reason this solution seems inelegant to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the borderstyle to underline. Or add some tikz and other code to the layout. In the second case set the colors to transparent. It is also often quite useful to move the field a bit down to get a better alignment with the label:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full-]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\renewcommand\LayoutTextField[2]{%
 #2}

Name: \TextField[width=4cm,borderstyle=U]{nameA}{\rule{4cm}{.4pt}}

 \renewcommand\LayoutTextField[2]{%
   \raisebox{-3.2pt}{\tikz[overlay]\draw[dashed](0,-0.2\dp\strutbox)--++(\csname Fld@width\endcsname,0pt);#2}}

 Name: \TextField[width=4cm,bordercolor={},backgroundcolor={}]{nameB}{\rule{4cm}{.4pt}}


 \renewcommand\LayoutTextField[2]{%
  \raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\cleaders \hbox to .44em{\hss.\hss}\hskip\csname Fld@width\endcsname}}#2}

 Name: \TextField[width=4cm,bordercolor={},backgroundcolor={}]{nameC}{\rule{4cm}{.4pt}}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks. I tried looking for a borderstyle option in the `hyperref` manual but couldn't find any. I love the simplicity of that solution. Also, I'm doing it the other way round from what you suggested. I added a `raisebox` to the label to align it with the text field better.

Comment: Ok `borderstyle=U` doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me as you can see in the screenshot, but it can depend on the pdf viewer.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. It works in Acrobat. That's strange. I guess the TikZ solution is the only feasible one then.

Comment: I'm also wondering where the syntax for `borderstyle=U` is documented. I couldn't find anything in http://ctan.mirror.colo-serv.net/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I don't remember but I probably found it while looking in the code. hyperref has a number of undocumented options.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Why does I need to suppress the 3 `{\rule{4cm}{.4pt}}` at the end of the `\TextField` command? If I keep it, I obtain 3 lines at the right of the 3 text fields. I can also confirm that `borderstyle=U` does nothing in my PDF reader (Preview.app from macOS): I obtain the default red box. And yes, we need a "missing manual" for the **hyperrref** package. Hope someone will write it in the future.