# How to create a fillable PDF in table format from MS word using Overleaf

Tags: hyperref, pdf, overleaf

I am looking to create a fillable PDF for a response sheet in table format as shown below. [image]

This is screenshot of how the response sheet looks like and I can't seem to find a way to enable people to fill in the downloaded PDF response sheet. Have been figuring out how to do so using `hyperref`

any help will be appreciated.

How can i integrate \begin{form} and \begin{tabular}?

Comment: You can do that with `hyperref`, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398905/typesetting-fillable-pdf-forms-with-hyperref. But that works only with Acrobat Reader (so that means that it doesn't work on Overleaf, and it also doesn't work with a lot of PDF viewers used by the people that should fill out this form).

Comment: Thank you for the tip. how can i integrate it in a table as shown above? I can only seem to do it outside a table form. @Marijn